# React bootstrap navbar do not have any design or do not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I installed react-bootstrap and bootstrap and its test for my website but its do not have any design and I do not know what is happened.
here is all code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

export function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">

                <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" sticky="top">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React Bootstrap Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="#action">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#action/2.1">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#action/2.2">About Us</Nav.Link>
                            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                            </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                        <Form inline>
                            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                            <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}
```

its a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported bootstrap css?

As it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css) you should import bootstrap css styles.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

for css you should be import : import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

for scss : @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

and ....

check documentation : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

You have to also import the Bootstrap CSS file at the top.

`import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`

So that react knows what style properties it should apply in your app's return JSX snippet.